# EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file folder permission issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run a Maintenance Cleanup Task to remove .bak files older than 2 days (simple enough).

Been trying all variety of .bak, BAK, .*., and editing the path, but the files are still not getting removed even though I receive a "job succeeded" log message.

I'm at the point where I believe it's a folder permission issue.

How do I make sure my SA has the proper permissions to remove files from a folder?

T-SQL:
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\',N'BAK',N'2012-06-21T11:35:59',1

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your whole `exec master.dbo.xp_delete_file` command with parameters.

Comment: T-SQL: EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\',N'BAK',N'2012-06-21T11:35:59',1

Answer (score 0):

I always have domain account with some (in your case sa) privilages on sql server. Then you add domain login to folder.